# Make a browser write content to the page file windows 10

Tags: windows-10, browser

I've heard that Windows 10 has the ability to write the inactive browser contents to the page file. Thereby releasing RAM for other applications to use. Is there a way I can make the browser write most of its content to the page file and store very limited data onto the RAM?

(Windows 10, updated, Chromium Based Brows

Comment: Windows manages this itself and does it well.

Comment: But what if we wish to optimise it more? Like an SSD Page file loading is certainly slower than RAM loading, but it benefits one using multiple software at the same time. 

Comment: The OS is in charge of memory management, not any individual app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Chromium Based Browsers:

The exact option of paging isn't available. But a suitable alternative is to use the *Experimental* Tab Freezing/Tab Discarding. It kills all the scripts and connections, stores form and other important data being filled on the webpage for individual tabs. You can manually discard individual tabs. And when you click on the tab again, it reloads with all the data(forms, etc)

You have to activate the experimental flags `chrome://flags/#show-saved-copy` and `chrome://flags/#enable-tab-discarding` (Replace `chrome` with your browser code). You will find the discarded  tabs in `chrome://discards`.

More information can be found here. [Tab Discarding in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/tab-discarding)

Answer (score 1):

This operation is colloquially called “working set trimming”. It effectively moves all of a process’ memory to the page file from which the required parts are then loaded again on demand. You can trigger this globally for all processes using RAMMap (“Empty working sets”). See also [SetProcessWorkingSetSize function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setprocessworkingsetsize).

Firefox has/had a [non-default preference `config.trim_on_minimize`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Config.trim_on_minimize) that does what it says: Empty the working set when minimizing the browser.

However, this is an indiscriminate operation; it does not care about how in-memory data is structured or related. Furthermore, it does not free up memory (“commit limit”). Leaving data in RAM until it is otherwise required is much better for overall performance and responsiveness.

Windows naturally moves not recently used pages to the page file over time, as other processes require RAM. You should never have to do this manually.

Comment: Agreed, I however have a very low-end hardware and the effect of tab freezing is very apparent on my device. But I will definitely keep the advice in mind. Thanks :)

Comment: Tab freezing as you describe it in your answer is something different entirely. It’s what you want. What this question was originally about isn’t.